# Out of memory error when marshalling large attachments

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws, axiom

I'm using spring ws on the server side with a AxiomSoapmessageFactory:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory">
       <property name="payloadCaching" value="true"/>
        <!-- Need to figure out the appropriate directory -->
       <property name="attachmentCacheDir" value="..."/>
    </bean>
```

This works fine when the services are ingesting a message. However, when the services attempt to serve up a large message I get Java out of memory exception.  Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:94)
        at org.apache.axiom.mime.impl.axiom.MultipartWriterImpl$PartOutputStream.write(MultipartWriterImpl.java:42)
        at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:294)
        at org.apache.axiom.mime.impl.axiom.MultipartWriterImpl.writePart(MultipartWriterImpl.java:116)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMMultipartWriter.writePart(OMMultipartWriter.java:136)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MIMEOutputUtils.writeSOAPWithAttachmentsMessage(MIMEOutputUtils.java:269)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessage.writeSwAMessage(AxiomSoapMessage.java:298)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessage.writeTo(AxiomSoapMessage.java:248)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.getMessageContent(MessageDispatcher.java:192)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:174)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.ErrorAwareWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(ErrorAwareWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:42)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet2.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet2.java:148)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

The problem seems to be that the services are attempting to read the whole attachment into memory prior to writing it out. Is there a way to stream the attachment?

I'm running this in a Tomcat instance on OSX 10.6.7 java --version =

java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truns out this was caused by turning message tracing on. When message tracing is on the MessageSender (at least in spring-ws 1.5.9) tries to copy the entire message into a ByteArrayOutputString and then converts the whole thing into a  string.  The offending functions are MessageSender.recieve and MessageSender.getContent

```
  public void receive(MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {
    // Let's keep a reference to the request content as it came in, it might be changed by interceptors in dispatch()
    String requestContent = "";
    if (receivedMessageTracingLogger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        requestContent = getMessageContent(messageContext.getRequest());
        receivedMessageTracingLogger.trace("Received request [" + requestContent + "]");
    }
    else if (receivedMessageTracingLogger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        receivedMessageTracingLogger.debug("Received request [" + messageContext.getRequest() + "]");
    }
    dispatch(messageContext);
    if (messageContext.hasResponse()) {
        WebServiceMessage response = messageContext.getResponse();
        if (sentMessageTracingLogger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            String responseContent = getMessageContent(response);
            sentMessageTracingLogger.trace("Sent response [" + responseContent + "] for request [" +
                            requestContent + "]");
        }
        else if (sentMessageTracingLogger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            sentMessageTracingLogger.debug("Sent response [" + response + "] for request [" +
                    messageContext.getRequest() + "]");
        }
    }
    else if (sentMessageTracingLogger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        sentMessageTracingLogger
                .debug("MessageDispatcher with name '" + beanName + "' sends no response for request [" +
                        messageContext.getRequest() + "]");
    }

    private String getMessageContent(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    message.writeTo(bos);
    return bos.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the following parameters to allow for more memory?

-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=256m

Comment: I have to work with the amount of heap space that is allocated to the server, so I can't increase the amount of heap space, I need the attachment to be streamed

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set the attachmentCaching property to true.  The default is false.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. That turned out to be the solution to my next out of memory error.